# migration in laravel in docker

Tags: mysql, laravel, docker, docker-compose

encountered a problem that when I run

```
php artisan migrate
```

in a container with my application, I get the following error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/66Lvf.png)

Before calling the

```
php artisan migrate
```

command, in the mysql container I selected which database to work with (**use rating;**)

I will further describe the construction of my docker assembly to answer any questions you may have.

docker-compse.yml with database setting:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PnLKg.png)

.env with database settings: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Xncv.png)

database.php with settings (from Laravel): [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yrxs6.png)

I tried changing DB_HOST from localhost to 127.0.0.1, to a container(rating-db) or service name (lar-db), all to no avail.

Upd:
databases: [databases](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mpVE8.png)

Comment: Docker most of the time cannot use your "local" databases, so you must have a database dump file for it to actually load your db correctly. Read more here https://budiaramdhanrindi.medium.com/how-to-import-database-in-mysql-in-docker-c92785dce36a

Comment: @dz0nika So I need to create a database locally, dump it and then load it into docker?

Comment: Not 100% sure if there is a workaround but every project I've worked with docker had a separate dump that loads with the makefile

Comment: @dz0nika I was a bit surprised, because it makes sense to make dumps if you already have a database ready. And I'm doing it from 0. If docker requires a dump for a clean database, that's mega weird from docker's side

Comment: Try this solution https://cadu.dev/creating-a-docker-image-with-database-preloaded/ maybe it can help

Comment: @dz0nika OK, thank you. But what about the database which is automatically created when docker-compose build in my case? (rating)
If I create a database dump with the same name, won't they conflict?

Comment: @dz0nika I just don't know if in this case I will create 2 databases (one from the container build and one from the dump), or if the dump always overwrites the default database (i.e. only one database from the dump will be created)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found the solution myself. What was written to me in the comments under the question turned out to be useless in this case. And I would like to make sure no one has any misconceptions about databases in the docker - you can create and use empty databases, you don't need dumps for that.

The answer to my question:

Pretty hard to believe it right away, but in the .env file for Laravel you had to specify in the DB_HOST line the name of the service that hosts mysql. In my case the service is called "rating-db" (from docker-compose.yml).

A screenshot of the .env is attached to the question. Just find "DB_HOST" there and replace the value with the name of your mysql service from docker-compose.yml

Comment: This may be useful for some people, but you don't have to select the database in the mysql container either. If the database name is specified in your .env and is correct, everything will work automatically (even with a few databases).